# Почему Composer устанавливает старую версию Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, composer

Пытаюсь установить Laravel при помощи Composer, но устанавливается версия Laravel 5.8, хотя уже давно есть версии 6.* . После установки Сomposer, я его обновил при помощи команды `composer self-update`. Далее установил глобально Larevel при помощи команды `composer global require laravel/installer`, перешёл в нужную директорию и при помощи команды запустил установку Laravel `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel slien`. В общем, стандартная процедура, но почему-то Composer устанавливает версию 5.8.36. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, что делаю не правильно? Как поставить 6 версию при помощи Composer?

Comment: Какая у вас версия `php`? Если пхп не поддерживает последнюю версию ларавел, то установиться последняя поддерживающая версия

Comment: Использую OpenServer, на момент установки была версия PHP 7.1. Сейчас попробую установить на PHP 7.3.

Comment: С версией `PHP 7.3` устанавливается `Laravel 6.8`. Значит проблема была в этом. Благодарю!